# On Appear only works for 1st instance... how can I change that

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, swift5

I have a section of code that makes my text appear mid screen and pulse in and out briefly, perfect. BUT it only does it the first time the function is called. The following times it shows the text but not the animation.

```
VStack {
    GameView(showText: self.$showText, imageName: self.$imageName)
    Button(action: {
        withAnimation {
            self.showText.toggle()
            self.attempts += 1

        }
    }, label: {
        Text("Show / Hide Text")
    })
}
    if self.showText {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Image(imageName)
                //animation here
                .scaleEffect(scale)

                    .onAppear{

                        let baseAnimation = Animation.easeInOut(duration: 0.5)
                        let repeated = baseAnimation.repeatForever(autoreverses: true)

                        return withAnimation(repeated) {
                            self.scale = 0.5


                        }


                }

                Spacer()
            }
            Spacer()
        }


    }


}
```

should I be using something other than On Appear?

thanks
Always Striving

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On hide it is not reset `scale` state, so no changes in state on next show, so no animation. Just add below `.onAppear`

```
.onDisappear {
    self.scale = 1
}
```